# mypy check project with pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I trying to use [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for checking of project which uses [pyqt5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5). To make my question more clear, I create synthetic example, instead of my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDateTime

def date_to_string(date: QDateTime) -> str:
    return date.toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss")

now = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
print(date_to_string(now))
```

when I run [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I got:

```
~/.local/bin/mypy test.py 
test.py:1: error: No library stub file for module 'PyQt5.QtCore'
test.py:1: note: (Stub files are from https://github.com/python/typeshed)
```

I found `/usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python/PyQt5.api`:

```
$ grep QDateTime /usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python/PyQt5.api  | grep toString
PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime.toString?4(Qt.DateFormat format=Qt.TextDate) -> QString
PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime.toString?4(QString) -> QString
PyQt5.QtCore.QLocale.toString?4(QDateTime, QString) -> QString
PyQt5.QtCore.QLocale.toString?4(QDateTime, QLocale.FormatType format=QLocale.LongFormat) -> QString
```

is this what [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) want?

How can I tell [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to use `/usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python/PyQt5.api`?

Also I have `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.pyi`, may be this file [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) want?

Comment: Yes, mypy needs the .pyi file.